# Start/Stop An Azure SQL Data Warehouse via Azure Rest API or Azure Management SDK

Tags: .net, http, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm going to create a .NET api that will be pinged consistently by my Node.Js server. When the server is being used, the api will stay awake. When the server is not being used, it will stop pinging, and the api will idle. I can use the global.asax file in the API to control the shutting down of the datawarehouse.

Is there a way to pause a SQL DW in C# via Azure Resource Management Client SDK? Or do I build a POST to the REST api manually?

I have been following the details on this blog post which I found helpful, but can not find a method in the ResourceMangementClient to pause a resource (my DW).

https://zimmergren.net/developing-with-azure-resource-manager-part-3-build-an-application-using-c-which-is-using-the-azure-resource-manager-apis/

If this is not possible, I can build a post manually for the REST api, as seen here (thanks to azure twitter support!):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases#Databases_Pause

## **Edit (Working answer below):

I was able to successfuly use the REST api to stop/start the DW, as seen in my answer below. I still don't know if it's possible to use the resource management SDK to do this.

Make sure you set up your authentication to use the rest API if you're trying to do this. Details can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: As far as I know, Azure App Service doesn't have any lifecycle events. You 'd need to check when the webapp is idle in application level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I used to properly turn off my DW via the Azure Rest API. I still am not sure if the Azure SDK has the possibility to do this.

```
    private static string AuthToken { get; set; }
    private static TokenCredentials TokenCredentials { get; set; }
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


    AuthToken = GetAuthorizationToken();
    TokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(AuthToken);

    createPost();


    private static string GetAuthorizationToken()
    {
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ServicePrincipalPassword);
        var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + AzureTenantId);
        var result = context.AcquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", cc);
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }

        return result.AccessToken;
    }

    public void createPost()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/MYGROUP/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/MYSERVER/databases/MYDW/pause?api-version=2014-04-01");

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AuthToken);

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
```